# React-router-v6 nested route only renders main route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Im trying to use a nested router for a todo list. I have categories and i want to navigate to the category by id. What i tried is :

```
<Routes>
   <Route path={"/todolist"} element={<TodoCategories />}>
   <Route path={":id"} element={<TodoList />} />
</Route>
```

And i also tried this ;

```
<Routes>
   <Route path={"/todolist/*"} element={<TodoCategories />}>
     <Route path={":id"} element={<TodoList />} />
   </Route>
 </Routes>
```

Url is changing in browser like ;

```
http://localhost:3000/todolist/development
```

But the TodoList element is not rendering. Only TodoCategories element is rendering. I tried some solutions but not working. Thanks for helps.

Comment: Are you trying to render something on "/todolist/development" or are you trying to render the `TodoList` component? It's on a different path than the URL.

Comment: Im trying to render TodoList component if i have a param in url

Comment: Sorry i couldnt understand. The path is true. It works if i try the route path like <Route path={"/todolist/:id"} element={<TodoList />} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on path `"/todolist/development"` but this doesn't match either of the paths in the routes, `"/todolist"` or `"/:id"`.

The second path should be `"/todolist/:id"` if you want to match and render on `"/todolist/development"`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={"/todolist"} element={<TodoCategories />}>
  <Route path={"/todolist/:id"} element={<TodoList />} />
</Route>
```